# Anonymous Type to Real Class Refactoring

Tags: c#, resharper, anonymous-types

Is there an easy way to refactor an anonymous type into a class? I frequently prototype my code with anonymous types, then have to go back and re implement the various classes as they need to be used beyond their local scope. I am using resharper and wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using ReSharper 5.1 *(I would expect this has been available since version 4, the first with C# 3.0 support)*, with the cursor anywhere from just before the `new` to just after the closing `}` in this code:

```
        var v = new {Name = "Brian"};
```

bring up the `Refactor This...` menu (typically with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and one of the options is `Replace Anonymous Type With Named Class...`, which brings up this dialog:

[image: ReSharper's Replace Anonymous Type With Named Class dialog]

Comment: Note that if the anonymous type has properties which are also anonymous types you have to refactor the properties to named types first.

Comment: Any way to do this without ReSharper ?