# Refactor Anonymous Type to Named Type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, anonymous-types

I love the ability to refactor -> extract method in Visual Studio.  Is there a similar fairly automated feature in VS that allows you to rapidly convert an anonymous type into a named type?

Consider this.  You're coding and start an anonymous type, such as:

```
var obj = foo.Select(c => new { ID = c.ID, Thing = c.Value }).ToList();
```

Then you realize thereafter that obj needs to be strongly typed class so that you can perform updates/writes to the properties in obj.  Then it's off to build a class.  It would be slick if you could just right click the anon obj select Convert To Named Type and a class would pop out.  Is there a built in VS (or free/open source) feature to do that?

The net results being something like:

```
public class [somename]
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Thing {get; set;}
}

.....

List<[somename]> = foo.Select(c => new [somename] { ID = c.ID, Thing = c.Value }).ToList();

.....
```

THANKS!

Comment: You can add the ReSharper extension : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291427/anonymous-type-to-real-class-refactoring

Comment: Using `var` does not make it an anonymous class. It is strongly typed regardless of whether you type out `List<T>` or `var`.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaoy312, I did run across ReSharper, but was more so curious if it that ability is actually in VS somewhere and I've just missed it.  Seems like it would be a useful built-in feature such as extract method.

Comment: Anonymous type does have value in LINQ, esp when you use `GroupBy`, `Distinct` because it uses structural comparison. In these cases, converting to real type will get the wrong result

Comment: @dharms `var` does not make it an anonymous class. The `.Select()` that is selecting the anonymous class does.

Comment: @TedKrapf I believe there is no such built-in function in VS yet. Another place you can look at is the new Rosyln compiler which allow you to write custom code refactoring strategy : http://www.strathweb.com/2014/10/building-refactoring-tools-code-fixes-roslyn/

Comment: @MattRowland you're right I missed the anonymous class inside.

Comment: @Xiaoy312, thanks, I wasn't aware of Rosyln.  I just scanned through the site/link.  It looks really slick! if I ever get some free time I'll have to seriously look into that.

Comment: @CuongLe That's not true, it's just means that the real type you create from this process would need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, just like an anonymous class would.  Of course, if you skipped that step, (just like if you skipped any other portion of the definition of the anonymous types) then yes, it would function differently than the anonymous type.